# Python tesseract, swig_import_helper(), Missing Dll

Tags: python, dll, swig, tesseract

Initially, `import tesseract` was working well. After playing with Google App Engine SDK(installing/Deploying), editing things on my files to check out the result and playing with some internal code, `import python` started showing this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HEAA\Desktop\ocr2.py", line 9, in <module>
    import tesseract
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tesseract.py", line 26, in <module>
    _tesseract = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tesseract.py", line 22, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_tesseract', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Im on Windows 7, python 2.7.5.

**What shall I do to resolve this?**

Reinstalled python.

uninstalled googleAppEngine.

Installed depends22_x86. Tested the tesseract.pyd with "depends22_x86" --> There are quite few file missing errors over there, but im unsure how to resolve it.

PS: I am not a Pro in Python

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this? I am having the same problem.